# Asp.Net MVC and Report Viewer Control

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reportviewer, webforms

I have an Asp.Net MVC page that links out to a Asp.net web form with a report viewer control on it.  The web form opens in a new window, and displays a report properly when clicking on the link on my MVC page.  
However when I close the my broswer window while the report is processing, and try to open it again, the page hangs and eventually gives me a page can not be displayed error.

Thoughts?

Comment: How do you open the browser window again after closing it?

Comment: The report opens in a new window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initial thoughts from me are;

1)  Not closing objects correctly on errors which might happen when browser windows are closed unexpectadly.
2)  Report still running and not allowing another instance.  easy to prove.  when you get the error, close the window and click the report again.  if you get your report then this may be a candidate.
3)  Caching issues.  try setting IE to refresh on every visit.

I think 1 or 2 are likely as I've seen this before on one of my applications where processing was interuppted.